# Copying files from a local directory to an online cluster

Tags: python, copy, cluster-computing, local, pwd

How can I copy a file from a local directory to an online cluster, while I'm logged in the cluster? Let say I'm currently at

```
online-user@ldas-grid
```

which `pwd` gives me

> /home/online-user

and I want to copy a file to above mentioned online cluster from a local folder at

> offline-user@my-pc-name

which `pwd` gives me

> /Users/offline-user

Comment: Can you just use scp?

Comment: how can I use it? Please explain more for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

simply `scp file online-user@ldas-grid:` will copy file `file` from your current directory to your home directory on the cluster.

- Copy from local to cluster while connected on local: `scp file online-user@ldas-grid:`
- Copy from local to cluster while connected on cluster: `scp offline-user@my-pc-name:file .`
- Copy from cluster to local while connected on local: `scp online-user@ldas-grid:file .`
- Copy from cluster to local while connected on cluster: `scp file offline-user@my-pc-name:`

Alternatively, you can use `rsync`.

See

- `man scp`
- `man rsync`

for more information

Comment: Sorry to be too naive but I don't know how can I get back to my local home from the cluster.

Comment: And another thing, suppose that I want to copy a file from local to cluster while I'm on the cluster. How can I do this?

Comment: To exit an ssh session, hit control-d, type exit or type logout.  It depends, a little bit, on what shell you're in, but one of those 3 should work.

Comment: To pull data from your desktop to the cluster, initiated from the cluster, you need to know the hostname of your desktop.  Then: "scp desktop.host.name:~/file-name ."

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me. I'm looking for somrthing with gsiscp.